# Azure delegated mail reading across office365 domain (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, npm, exchange-server

Trying to read/write/update the emails of each user within the domain on office365. I'm using Azure Active Directory and an Azure app. I'm the account admin. I've turned on a whole load of permissions at this stage as not sure which ones are necessary.

I'm programming in Nodejs. So...

1. Authenticate my app, using OAuth, against Azure so that I can access my own application. <- WORKS.
2. Request admin rights against the account at this URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id='+clientID+'&redirect_uri'+uri` where `clientID` and `uri` are replaced. This redirects me to authentication against Microsoft platform. You can see all the permissions I have requested (while debugging) here:
   [image]
3. Once I accept the permissions it returns me to my app, where it requests a token from: `https://login.windows.net/[my-app-tenant-id]/oauth2/token`. That returns the access token. So far so good
4. After that, I then try and use this token to read a user of my organisations emails (for instance me, but there are a few users I have tried it with). It goes to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/[userEmailAddress@domain.com/messages`. I pass the token as a `bearer`. 
   This is the problem, I get

   {
     "error": {
       "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
       "message": "Access token validation failure.",
       "innerError": {
         "request-id": "[request-id]",
         "date": "2017-03-21T17:31:24"
       }
     }
   }

I have tried this with a couple of URLs, for instance the outlook API, with this url `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0`. I think however that is for simple OAuth and wouldn't work this way anyway.

If anyone can explain how to get the access token to be valid, would be great.

FYI, I am also, simultaneously testing out the npm library `azure-graphapi` and using:

```
    var clientID = '[client id]'
    var clientSecret = '[client secret]'
    var tenant = '[tenant id]'
    var graph = new GraphAPI(tenant, clientID, clientSecret);
    graph.get('users/', function(err, user) {
        resp.json({users: user});    
    })
```

I can get the list of users. So perhaps I am being stupid and somehow I can use this to read a users email?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have made a mistake in the request header to get access token.

As you can see, I got a token by sending a POST request to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint and passed the value `mail.read` to the `scope` parameter in this request.

[image]

Now, I am able to get emails of the user with that token.

[image]

Comment: So I think this is for standard oAuth.... I'm trying to create an app that can act on behalf of the users in AD rather than a user logging in and accessing their own data....